# Backspace removes two characters at a time in text field in FF 3.6.18

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am facing an issue with a textbox in HTML. If I use backspace to clear the text written in the text box, it removes two characters at time instead of one. I am using such kind of syntax for text field :-

```
<input name="IPAddress" id="ipaddress10" type="text" size="12" value="0" 
       onblur="" style="text-align: left">
```

Comment: There's a space missing after the `value` attribute. Is this really a minimal test case? If your CSS doesn't matter, why did you tag with [css]?

Answer (score -1):

Try with JavaScript disabled. If it removes only one space, it means that there is a problem with your JavaScript code.